# Find questions that compose the Sportsmanship badge?

Tags: support, search

How to search my answers with score of 1+ in questions where I upvoted someone else's answer?

Specifically talking about the Sportsmanship badge.

When I click to track badges, it shows:

[image]

How do I find these above `11` questions?

Comment: A relevant query to help you find posts to consider upvoting: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/295957/answers-with-competing-answers-to-consider-voting-on-to-get-sportsmanship

Comment: Is hunting a sportsmanship badge not considered unsportsmanlike?